# Having trouble binding ViewModel to ComboBox

Tags: c#, viewmodel

I have a viewmodel setup as the following

```
public class cDriveListVM
{
    public string Drive { get; set; }
    public cDriveListVM(string name)
    {
        Drive = name;
    }
}
```

I declare the observablecollection in the window and set its datacontext to this observable collection.

```
public ObservableCollection<cDriveListVM> DriveList { get; set; }
private void dl()
{
    DriveList = new ObservableCollection<cDriveListVM>();
    DriveList.Add(new cDriveListVM("drive 1"));
    DriveList.Add(new cDriveListVM("drive 2"));
    this.DataContext = DriveList;
}
```

Xml for combobox:

```
<ComboBox x:Name="Drive_ComboBox" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Drive}" HorizontalAlignment="Center" IsReadOnly="True" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" Width="300" Margin="10" SelectionChanged="Drive_Changed" Height="22" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
```

I am just learning how to use Viewmodel so I am unsure what I am doing wrong, any help would be appreciated. I updated the xml file it results in the following combbox.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a few problems with this code.

One, the binding is set up wrong. Since the property with the viewmodel collection is `DriveList`, the binding should be `ItemsSource="{Binding Path=DriveList}"`.

Two, you are attempting to display a field from your viewmodel, which is not doable. WPF's binding engine only works with properties, so the viewmodel should have a property:

```
public string Drive { get; set; }
```

And finally, the `DisplayMemberPath` should match the property name from the viewmodel: `DisplayMemberPath="Drive"`.

**Update:** I just noticed that the `DataContext` is the observable collection itself -- I probably missed it on the first read. In that case, you want to bind directly to the data context:

```
ItemsSource="{Binding}"
```

And set `DisplayMemberPath` to the property you want to display:

```
DisplayMemberPath="Drive"
```

Comment: I tried your suggestions but it still didn't work, so I changed the xml to what I now have in the above. But the combobox is displaying the strings incorrectly

Comment: @yawnobleix: I updated the answer -- not sure why I missed the `DataContext` part earlier, but the update should work now.

Comment: ok that works perfectly, one last question if I want to have the observablecollection available globally how would you recommend doing that?

Comment: @yawnobleix: Depends on how your application is structured really, the obvious dead simple approach is to make it a `static` property of some class but that rather quick and dirty.